# How to generate a KML with nested attributes and attributes with cardinality greater than one

Tags: kml

I have a set of events that I want to export to KML. Those events have nested attributes and attributes with cardinality greater than one  (maxOccur > 1).

Here is an example of one event presented as JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2018-01-01",
    "client": {
        "name": "Brad",
        "since": "2017-12-01"
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "P1",
            "quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "P2",
            "quantity": 40
        },
    ]
}
```

One option that we are considering is use an arbitrary XML at ExtendedData. This option sounds good for Machine-to-Machine data interchange, but not for human read, because the Google Earth does not show those data very well in balloons:

```
<ExtendedData>
    <id>1</id>
    <date>2018-01-01</date>
    <client>
        <name>Brad</name>
        <since>2017-12-01</since>
    </client>
    <products>
        <product>
            <name>P1</name>
            <quantity>20</quantity>
        </product>
        <product>
            <name>P2</name>
            <quantity>40</quantity>
        </product>
    </products>
</ExtendedData>
```

Other option that we are considering is use Schema + SchemaData + BallonStyle, but the cardinality and nested attributes are not supported...

```
<Schema name="myEvent" id="myEvent">     
    <SimpleField type="int" name="id">       
        <displayName>Event id</displayName>     
    </SimpleField>
    <SimpleField type="string" name="date">       
        <displayName>Event date</displayName>     
    </SimpleField>

    <!-- workaround to nested data -->
    <SimpleField type="string" name="clientName">       
        <displayName>Client name</displayName>     
    </SimpleField>
    <SimpleField type="string" name="clientSince">       
        <displayName>Client since</displayName>     
    </SimpleField>

    <!-- no idea how present attributes with more than one occurrence -->
</Schema>
```

There is another option that we should consider?

Answer (score 3):

Data and SimpleData elements in KML [ExtendedData](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata) are limited to name/value pairs with values as text but custom XML is allowed using a different namespace.

You can add arbitrary XML data to a Feature in KML from a non-KML XML namespace like Dublin core, RDF, or your own namespace. Here is a related [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata?csw=1).

Here's an example with arbitrary Dublin core XML in KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>ExtendedData Test with Dublin core XML</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Test data</name>
            <ExtendedData xmlns:ns="http://example.org/myapp/">
                <ns:metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
                 <dc:description>
      KML features a rich mix of
      metadata information and services for the XML community.
                 </dc:description>
                 <dc:subject>XML, RDF, metadata, information
                  syndication services</dc:subject>
                 <dc:identifier>http://earth.google.com</dc:identifier>    
                 <dc:language>en-us</dc:language>
                 <dc:date>2000-10-13</dc:date>
                 <dc:rights>Copyright 2000, O'Reilly Network</dc:rights>
                 <dc:publisher>O'Reilly and Associates, Inc.</dc:publisher>
                </ns:metadata>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-71.7571,42.953</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

With your own namespace, you can store whatever XML you want with whatever nesting.

```xml
<Placemark>
   <name>Test data</name>
   <ExtendedData>
    <data xmlns="urn:my.org:data"> 
     <id>1</id>
     <date>2018-01-01</date>
     <client>
        <name>Brad</name>
        <since>2017-12-01</since>
     </client>
     <products>
        <product>
            <name>P1</name>
            <quantity>20</quantity>
        </product>
        <product>
            <name>P2</name>
            <quantity>40</quantity>
        </product>
     </products>
   </data>
   </ExtendedData>
</Placemark>
```

Note however that this approach passes along the data within the KML for a machine-to-machine exchange since Google Earth does not process nor display this type of data. A third party application could take advantage of this type of XML data contained within the KML.

If you want at least part of the data to be human-readable via Google Earth, consider a hybrid solution with name-value pairs in Data/value elements for the simple values and a custom XML element for the more complex nested XML data.

```xml
<Placemark>
    <name>Test data</name>
    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name="id">
            <value>123</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="date">
            <value>2018-01-01</value>
        </Data>
        <customData xmlns="urn:custom">
            <client>
                <name>Brad</name>
                <since>2017-12-01</since>
            </client>
        </customData>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-71.7571,42.953</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: If you choose to add your own namespace, as in your last example, how do you define it? Can you include a relevant link to how to define your own namespace? The Google link does not tell you how to do this.

Comment: You just define a XML namespace as a URI as you would any namespace in XML only it must be anything other than `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2`. See [XML Namespace Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/)

Comment: I worded that very badly. I am confused about `xmlns="uri:other"` So, browsing that document, it seems like the uri in the namespace can be arbitrary? It doesn't have to point to an actual document? We could use xmlns="uri:namespace-uris-confuse-me" and it would validate?

Comment: `uri:other` just a way of saying any URI (or URL); e.g. `xmlns="urn:any-uri-goes-here"`